# Laravel 8 update JSON column value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update the value of a `json` column type for all of my users, my query that I'm running through Tinker doesn't give any errors, it just returns `0` and the columns remain unchanged, what am I doing wrong?

```php
User::where('notification_preferences')->update(['notification_preferences' => [
  'domains' => [
    'expiry' => [
      'mail' => true,
      'database' => true
    ]
  ]
]])
```

My columns on my rows currently has the value of...

```
{
    "expiry_alerts": true
}
```

Comment: It looks as if the second argument is missing in your WHERE .  User::where('notification_preferences', ***here****)- ? And I do not understand the expiry_alerts annotation as it is not at all included in the query?

Comment: I removed ***here**** because it didn't work, was getting an error. In terms of not understanding `expiry_alerts`, there is nothing else to see, the extent of updating a column's value is as per my description and nothing more

Comment: Removing the condition in a where statement is no solution.  ;-) your question should have been "what is the problem with my condition" not just delete the condition and wonder why you get ZERO results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I have read the comment below it came clear to me that you used the wrong syntax for the WHERE query of a JSON column.  You have to use the  **->** operator.

For further information please see https://mattstauffer.com/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3/
&
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

It should work like this:

```
User::where('notification_preferences->expiry-alerts',true)->update(['notification_preferences' => [
  'domains' => [
    'expiry' => [
      'mail' => true,
      'database' => true
    ]
  ]
]])
```

Comment: This was the just first example i found in the manual .. I have no idea about laravel ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is your where clause `User::where('notification_preferences')`, if you express this to sql `User::where('notification_preferences')->toSql()`, you will notice something like this

`from users where notification_preferences is null...`, probably this is the reason why the update is not executed.

Comment: My `notification_preferences` column is of the type `json`. I have 3 users, each user has the following json in that column `{ "expiry_alerts": true }`. I now need to change the value of that to the json as per my description, I've tried adding `User::where('notification_preferences', ["expiry_alerts": true])->toSql()` which doesn't work, and also `User::where('notification_preferences', ["expiry_alerts" => true])->toSql()`. What am I missing?

Comment: This is the wrong syntax for JSON columns. Please look at my answer for the correct syntax.

Comment: This comment should have been posted into the original question.  Then it would have been easier to understand the problem ;-)